# Profile 'API only' permission not available on Developer edition

Tags: permissions

I have a developer edition and when I search for 'API only' permission on profile, it is not available.
For which Salesforce org edition 'API only' permission is available? or Do I have to contact Salesforce to enable that permission?
Can anyone help with this?
Thanks in advance.